# how do I display the values of an object in object array when user selects an option in select element?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, select

I have a seperate array with objects (the values of each option). Each object has three keys (values). The user can also add their own object through input. I wonder how I can display all three key values when the option is selected.

I thought of pushing the selected object into a seperate array and then loop the key values to display but I cant figure out how.

[I would like for the three values to appear on each line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Kgf5.png)

this is the object array:

```
const data = [
   {
    id: 1,
    field_1: "xxx",
    field_2: "xxx",
    field_3: "xxx",
  },
  {
     id: 2,
  field_1: "yyy",
  field_2: "yyy",
  field_3: "yyy",
},
 ];
```

the html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="input">
    <input placeholder="Field 1" id="field_1" class="field">
    <input placeholder="Field 2" id="field_2" class="field">
    <input placeholder="Field 3" id="field_3" class="field">

</div>

<div id="select">
<select id="select-el" onchange="show()">
    <option>Choose an Option</option>
</select>
<ul id="ul-el">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

the js:

```
 function userInput(){
 let newInput = {
  id: data.length + 1,
  field_1: document.getElementById("field_1").value,
  field_2: document.getElementById("field_2").value,
  field_3: document.getElementById("field_3").value,
}
data.push(newInput);
console.log(data);
}


let sel = document.getElementById("select-el");
function newop(first){
   let opt = document.createElement("option");
   opt.text = first.field_1;
   opt.value = first.field_1;
   opt.value = first.field_2;
   opt.value = first.field_3;
   sel.appendChild(opt);
 };
  array_each(data, newop);

 function newOption(){
let newOp = new_dom_element({
    tag: "option",
    parent: document.getElementById("select-el"),
    class: "newop"
})

newOp.innerText =  document.getElementById("field_1").value ;
  }


function show(){
 

  }



 array_find(data, show);
```

Comment: Would really help the rest of us to help you if you would share some code. 
Then we can give you an answer based on your code instead of some foo bar generic unclear answer :)

Answer (score 0):

**Please if you have any questions don't hesitate to ask **

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <label for="oobjects">Choose an Object:</label>
    <select id="object-container" name="objects" onchange="changeHandler(this.value)">
    </select>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="id" name="id" value="4">
        <input type="text" id="field_1" name="field_1" value="ddd">
        <input type="text" id="field_2" name="field_2" value="ddd">
        <input type="text" id="field_3" name="field_3" value="ddd">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <h1 id="h1">xxx</h1>
    <h1 id="h2">xxx</h1>
    <h1 id="h3">xxx</h1>
    <script>
        //array
        const data = [
            {
                id: 1,
                field_1: "xxx",
                field_2: "xxx",
                field_3: "xxx",
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                field_1: "yyy",
                field_2: "yyy",
                field_3: "yyy",
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                field_1: "zzz",
                field_2: "zzz",
                field_3: "zzz",
            },
        ];
        //initialize select element
        const selectContainer = document.getElementById('object-container')
        //looping inside the array to display the options
        data.forEach(element => {
            const opt = document.createElement('option');
            opt.value = element.id;
            opt.innerHTML = element.id;
            selectContainer.appendChild(opt);
        });
        function changeHandler(e) {
            const h1 = document.getElementById('h1')
            const h2 = document.getElementById('h2')
            const h3 = document.getElementById('h3')
            const search = data.find(element => element.id == e && element)
            h1.innerHTML = search.field_1
            h2.innerHTML = search.field_2
            h3.innerHTML = search.field_3
        }
        document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            const formData = new FormData(e.target);
            const formProps = Object.fromEntries(formData);
            data.push(formProps)
            const opt = document.createElement('option');
            opt.value = formProps.id;
            opt.innerHTML = formProps.id;
            selectContainer.appendChild(opt);
        })

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```